# Finite $\alpha \approx \beta$ implies $\alpha = \beta$

Tags: set-theory

Assume that $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\alpha \approx \beta$ (there exists a bijection $f: \alpha \to \beta$), how should we use the bijection $f: \alpha \to \beta$ to prove that $\alpha = \beta$? This conclusion seems pretty straightforward, but I didn't find a good way to establish $=$ from $\approx$ directly.

Comment: Perhaps by induction? Then ultimately it follows from the uniqueness of the empty set.

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: @user set of natural numbers.

Comment: How is $\approx$ defined?

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 there exists a bijection as explained in the post.

Comment: @ZiqiFan Bijections are between sets. You said that that alpha and beta were natural numbers. Therefore they are not sets.

Comment: @BradyGilg Every object in math is a set. You may need some background in set theory to proceed.

Comment: Hint: For the case that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both not $0$: modify your bijection between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so it maps the largest element of $\alpha$ (i.e. $\alpha-1$) to the largest element of $\beta$ (i.e. $\beta-1$). Now you can restrict the bijection to a bijection of $\alpha - 1$ and $\beta - 1$. Use this to drive an induction argument.

Comment: @BradyGilg The identification is $0:=\emptyset,\, n+1:=n\cup\{ n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If any of $\alpha,\beta$ is $0$, the assertion is true by the uniqueness of the empty set.

Let this assertion be true for $\alpha < n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$.

Now, for $\alpha=n$, let $g : \beta \to \beta$ be a permutation such that $g \circ f(n-1)=\beta-1$ (identifying $\alpha$ with $\{0,1,\dots,\alpha-1\} \, \forall \alpha \in \Bbb N$).

Then, $(g \circ f)|_{n-1}$ is a bijection from $n-1$ to $\beta-1$. So, by induction hypothesis, $n-1=\beta-1 \implies n=\beta$.